# Kirchhoff's law when using an OpAmp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

The blue text is mine and the black text is given by my teacher

Comment: Please revise your question.  The text in your question mentions the variable "U", however, I do not see this in Figure 4.7 or 4.8.  Your refer to the relationships "U+ - Uin = 0" and "- U- - U1 = 0".  These are not valid equations.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Joppe. You can use MathJAX to fix your equations. Use `\$ U_+` for \$ U_+\$, `\$ U^+` for \$ U^+\$ and `\$ U_{R1} \$` for \$ U_{R1} \$, etc. See [primer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more advanced.

Comment: You actually don't need a closed circuit for KVL to work. You usually use a closed circuit path so you can calculate the individual drops along the path, but actually the sum of drops around a set of nodes will be 0 even if there's no connections between the nodes you choose.

Comment: [related](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/340132/6334)

Comment: (1) Don't you have a few closed circuits in your diagram?  (2) Have you considered Kirchoff's Current Law?

Comment: Okay, I don't think I grasp the concept completely, but is U+ = Uin because the resistance for the OpAmp input is infinite?

Answer (score 1):

\$U^{+} \$ is the voltage at +ve node of the opamp with respect to ground. The +ve node is connected to \$U_{in} \$ voltage source. So \$U^{+} = U_{in} \$

Same concept in the second circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Figure 4.7

The first line just says that \$ U^+ = U_{in} \$ which is very obvious because they are directly connected. To prove it by Kirchoff you need to draw in the internal resistance of the + input to ground. (Nobody would bother in this case because it can be considered infinite or open-circuit.)

Have a look at [Short and open circuits](https://filebox.ece.vt.edu/~LiaB/ECE2004/Notes/Short_Open_Circuits.pdf):

> An open circuit can be considered to be a resistor \$ R_{OC} = \infty \ \Omega \$. If we apply Ohm’s Law to an open circuit, then:
>   $$ V_{OC} = I_{OC} R_{OC} = I_{OC} (\infty \ \Omega) = ∞ \ \text V $$
>   So, the electromotive force, V, required to move electrons through a short circuit as a function of time, I, is infinite, no
>   matter how small the current is. Since we do not have circuits that have an infinite amount of voltage available, the
>   current that flows through an open circuit must be zero.

Does that help?

Comment: That's is the annoying thing, I know it is useless to use kirchhoff for this. But we are expected to for some reason.

Comment: See if the update helps.

Comment: @joppewesseling - "I know it is useless to use kirchhoff for this. But we are expected to for some reason." The reason is that they are dealing with the op amp currents, and are showing the current relations for ALL the op amp pins. In other words, for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that if you have a circuit with one voltage source, one resistor of 10 ohm and an infinite resistor, that the voltage over the 10 ohm resistor would be 0 because the infinite resistor would make the voltage drop the same amount that the source can deliver?

Comment: Correct. That's why, for example, we can measure the open-circuit voltage of a battery and then load it with a known resistor to work out the battery's internal resistance.

Comment: but then I don't understand over what the voltage U+ is in the circuit above, because in the opamp is an infinite resistor, or is the voltage U+ over that resistor?

Comment: I think that is the correct approach. \$ U^+ \$ is over the input impedance. It would be better if there was a ground (GND) symbol on the negative rail to indicate that was where all voltages are referenced from.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed my professor doesn't do that even though most op amp circuits use that, we didn't get a lot of explanation about grounds so I actually don't understand it completely, pretty annoying but I think I get the just of it now

Comment: Ground is easy. It is some reference point in the circuit that signals and voltages are referenced to. It is most often the battery negative but can be the middle as in +12 / 0 / -12 split rail power supplies. Think of it as the point where you will normally connect the black multimeter lead or the scope ground.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah that makes a lot more sense, thanks for all the help!